Filter a pandas DataFrame based on multiple columns with a corresponding list of values
I have a DataFrame that looks a bit like this:
        A      B      C      D  ...         G         H         I         J
0   First  First  First  First  ...  0.412470  0.758011  0.066926  0.877992
1   First  First  First  Third  ...  0.007162  0.957042  0.601337  0.636086
2   First  First  Third  First  ...  0.956398  0.640909  0.602861  0.679656
3   First  First  Third  Third  ...  0.905421  0.199685  0.471300  0.975808
4   First  Third  First  First  ...  0.378181  0.498606  0.865298  0.914407
5   First  Third  First  Third  ...  0.387706  0.247412  0.339593  0.431647
6   First  Third  Third  First  ...  0.582202  0.046199  0.496258  0.533133
7   First  Third  Third  Third  ...  0.877199  0.011512  0.338528  0.938252
8   Third  First  First  First  ...  0.446433  0.175686  0.115796  0.985400
9   Third  First  First  Third  ...  0.315839  0.252855  0.142463  0.929233
10  Third  First  Third  First  ...  0.192566  0.600732  0.434166  0.933182
11  Third  First  Third  Third  ...  0.380029  0.511411  0.672583  0.807731
12  Third  Third  First  First  ...  0.915590  0.507470  0.390135  0.303314
13  Third  Third  First  Third  ...  0.977414  0.062521  0.909845  0.314432
14  Third  Third  Third  First  ...  0.608958  0.384802  0.193425  0.689283
15  Third  Third  Third  Third  ...  0.496223  0.478222  0.076192  0.695453

[16 rows x 10 columns]

I also have a list (coming from elsewhere) with the values for A, B, C & D that I'm looking for, something like this:
expected = ['First', 'Third', 'First', 'Third']

I'd like to filter to find a row matching a certain set of ABCD values, where the expected values are in a list.  Something like this (which doesn't work):
# This looks neat, but doesn't work
rows = df[df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] == expected]]
rows

# Not what I was hoping for!
Out[17]: 
        A      B      C      D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   First    NaN  First    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   First    NaN  First  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   First    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   First    NaN    NaN  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   First  Third  First    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   First  Third  First  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   First  Third    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   First  Third    NaN  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8     NaN    NaN  First    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9     NaN    NaN  First  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
11    NaN    NaN    NaN  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
12    NaN  Third  First    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
13    NaN  Third  First  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
14    NaN  Third    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
15    NaN  Third    NaN  Third NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

I could use dropna(subset=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) to get the relevant rows, then extract the index and use it on the original table, but that's getting quite long-winded.
I know I can do this long-hand like this, but I'm wondering whether there's a neater way:
# This works, but is clunky:
rows = df[(df['A'] == expected[0]) & (df['B'] == expected[1]) & (df['C'] == expected[2]) & (df['D'] == expected[3])]
rows

# This is what I want:
Out[19]: 
       A      B      C      D  ...         G         H         I         J
5  First  Third  First  Third  ...  0.387706  0.247412  0.339593  0.431647

[1 rows x 10 columns]

Is there a simpler way of doing this?  My searching for filtering by lists just seems to come up with lots of isin suggestions, which aren't relevant.

You need select columns by [[]] first for subset, compare by list and test if all values are Trues by DataFrame.all:
expected = ['First', 'Third', 'First', 'Third']

rows = df[(df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] == expected).all(axis=1)]
print (rows)
       A      B      C      D  ...         G         H         I         J
5  First  Third  First  Third  ...  0.387706  0.247412  0.339593  0.431647

How it working:
print (df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']])
        A      B      C      D
0   First  First  First  First
1   First  First  First  Third
2   First  First  Third  First
3   First  First  Third  Third
4   First  Third  First  First
5   First  Third  First  Third
6   First  Third  Third  First
7   First  Third  Third  Third
8   Third  First  First  First
9   Third  First  First  Third
10  Third  First  Third  First
11  Third  First  Third  Third
12  Third  Third  First  First
13  Third  Third  First  Third
14  Third  Third  Third  First
15  Third  Third  Third  Third


print ((df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] == expected))
        A      B      C      D
0    True  False   True  False
1    True  False   True   True
2    True  False  False  False
3    True  False  False   True
4    True   True   True  False
5    True   True   True   True
6    True   True  False  False
7    True   True  False   True
8   False  False   True  False
9   False  False   True   True
10  False  False  False  False
11  False  False  False   True
12  False   True   True  False
13  False   True   True   True
14  False   True  False  False
15  False   True  False   True


print ((df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] == expected).all(axis=1))
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
dtype: bool


For fun, you could perform a query :
z = zip("ABCD", expected) # or `df.columns[:4]` or `[...]`

out = df.query(" and ".join(map("{0[0]} == {0[1]!r}".format, z)))

Output :
       A      B      C      D         G         H         I         J
5  First  Third  First  Third  0.387706  0.247412  0.339593  0.431647

[1 rows x 8 columns]

